# Confusing grep behaviour when using \s inside a negated character class

Tags: regex, grep

I have a regular expression which matches "x" if it is preceded by a non-space character other than `"` and any number of space characters:

```
[^"\s]\s*x
```

This works as expected in JavaScript:

```
$ node
> /[^"\s]\s*x/.test('x')
false
> /[^"\s]\s*x/.test(' x')
false
> /[^"\s]\s*x/.test('" x')
false
> /[^"\s]\s*x/.test(': x')
true
```

grep, though, behaves differently:

```
$ echo 'x' | grep '[^"\s]\s*x'

$ echo ' x' | grep '[^"\s]\s*x'
 x

$ echo '" x' | grep '[^"\s]\s*x'
" x

$ echo ': x' | grep '[^"\s]\s*x'
: x
```

Is there an explanation for this behaviour? How would I rewrite the regular expression for grep so it behaves as intended?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/grep-regular-expression-syntax.html) backslashes within `[]` are taken literally. Thus your negation group isn't "not a quotation mark or space character" but rather "not a quote, backslash, or s".

Try `[^"[:space:]]` instead?

Answer (score 3):

You can instruct grep to be Perl compatible with `-P` option:

```
$ echo 'x' | grep -P '[^"\s]\s*x'

$ echo ' x' | grep -P '[^"\s]\s*x'

$ echo '" x' | grep -P '[^"\s]\s*x'

$ echo ': x' | grep -P '[^"\s]\s*x'
: x
```

---

EDIT: not possible on Mac after they removed the `-P` switch

Comment: That's good to know, though the `-P` flag is not supported on a default OS X installation.

Comment: that's odd, they do list `-P` as a valid option on their [manual website page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/grep.1.html)